# Action Mailer NameError: Undefined local variable or method `“smtp'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, devise, actionmailer, nameerror

I'm attempting to set up Action Mailer to send reset password emails for Devise in my development environment. I'm receiving the following error when starting my local server: undefined local variable or method `“smtp', referring to the "address: “smtp.gmail.com”" line in my code. Here is the Action Mailer code I have added in my development.rb file:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: “smtp.gmail.com”,
port: 587,
domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
authentication: “plain”,
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```

I have the environment variables set up in a .env file in the root directory.
Thanks!

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's because you're using smart quotes, `“ ”` instead of `" "`, probably from copy/pasting. Replace these with standard quotes:

```
config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = true
config.action_mailer.perform_deliveries = true
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
address: "smtp.gmail.com",
port: 587,
domain: ENV["GMAIL_DOMAIN"],
authentication: "plain",
enable_starttls_auto: true,
user_name: ENV["GMAIL_USERNAME"],
password: ENV["GMAIL_PASSWORD"]
}
```